# Second Order Differential Equations when $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ are not constants

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm sorry if this question seems vague.

If I have a second-order differential equation of the form $$y''+ p(t) y'+q(t)y=g(t)$$ I understand how to solve for the complementary solutions and particular solutions if $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ are constants. But what if $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ are not constant and are functions of $t$. How do I compute the roots in this case.

I mean I certainly I could use variation of parameters but even then I need the fundamental set of solutions to get to the particular solution and I can get this if $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ are constants, but what if the case is that they are not constants and are functions of $t$. Most textbooks seem to take examples where $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ are constant.

Comment: Firstly, I assume you mean
$$y''+ p(t) y'+q(t)\color{red}{y}=g(t).$$
There is no general method in the case that $p$ and $q$ are not constant (the ansatz $y(t)=e^{rt}$ fails). Here is an example of a differential equation of the above form which requires a different method: [Cauchy–Euler equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation). However, variation of parameters is applicable as long as you are able to find the complementary solution.

Comment: There is the method of Frobenius, where you replace everything by its Taylor (or Laurent) series.  As long as everything exists and converges, you can work out the Taylor series of the solution.